# cannot invoke bootstrap plugin from javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to invoke bootstrap plugin for my webpage.

This is the plugin I am talking about:

[Select Picker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

[Select Picker 2](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)

When I invoke the plugin from my html file like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select class="selectpicker show-tick" id="tag" ata-style="btn-primary">
        <option>stocks</option>
        <option>bank</option>
        <option>card</option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('hide');
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is fine; the select boxes come with all CSS loaded as showed in the links above.

However, when I create the boxes dynamically from a JS file, the select boxes come up as plain Select boxes with no effects.

```
var selectElement1_act = document.createElement("select");
selectElement1_act.setAttribute("class", "selectpicker");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're invoking the function on the `window` load event, and when elements are created dynamically, they do not necessarily exist in the DOM at that point.

Since you're using jQuery, you'd be better to utilise the following code in your JS file instead:

```
$(function() {  
    var selectPicker = $('<select class="selectpicker" />');
    selectPicker.appendTo('body');
    selectPicker.selectpicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: Can you put together a demo page, please?